# あなたのこと、そんなでもなかったんだよ

Tags: meaning

> あなたのこと、そんなでもなかったんだよ…っ

It would clearly refer to the person she's talking to. It would be something like that she doesn't have that kind of feeling about him but I'd like to make sure and know if the ... changes the meaning there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it means "I didn't like you very much". Probably, そんなでもなかった in this sentence means そんな好きでもなかった.

Comment: I see thanks! One more thing, how would you translate the whole sentence literally? (to make sure I didn't miss something).

Comment: I think  "I didn't like you very much" is enough.

Comment: What do you mean by enough? That there's nothing more in the sentence?

Comment: Yes. In other words, "appropriate".

Comment: @thebeast A more literal translation would be "Regarding you, it's not (really) like that." or so... This そんな literally means "(as) such" or "(like) that", but it probably refers to her fondness

Comment: @naruto: Your literal translation would be better if it is written in past tense.